# Are a Human Replicator and a Human Cylon the same?

Tags: stargate, battlestar-galactica

I know they are from two different sci-fi series but if the Human Cylons and the Human Replicator would ever meet, would they consider themselves the same?

What makes them different? The same?

Comment: ..and what about a Human Dalek?

Comment: @MarkBeadles they are not even in the same field :-P

Comment: Voting to leave open, this is borderline Gorilla vs Shark, but a comparison of two sci-fi species sounds on-topic

Comment: Wait... why was this even closed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two of them are quite different and would not consider themselves the same.  While the Cylons destroyed humans, or tried to, their goal was their own existence without the interference of humans.  It's quite possible if humans were non-expansionist and showed no interest in interfering with Cylons, the Cylons may have let them be.  The Replicators were bent on domination and spreading out as much as they could.

Cylons also had individual intelligences.  Each humaniform Cylon was a distinct individual with distint thought patterns and a desire to remain alive through resurrection when their body was destroyed.  Replicators had more of a collective or group intelligence.  Any individual Replicator chip was not intelligent and didn't matter as just one unit.  It was assemblages of Replicators that had intelligences and personalities.

Cylons also had internal differences and there's no indication of this with Replicators.  And Replicators seemed to work purely on logic (other than the one that wanted SG1's help escaping the others), but humaniform Cylons had emotions and made emotional decisions.

Comment: Human-form Replicators were independent entities that acted of their own will.  The two most prominent human-form Replicators, Fifth and Replicarter, were also motivated entirely by their emotions, as was Reese, the android that initially created them.  Other than that, I agree

Comment: @Izkata: Sorry, I should have addressed them more directly.  Wasn't Fifth the one that wanted them to save him?  Even then, both Fifth and Replicarter were still aggregate intelligences, composed of a number of Replicators, where one chip, or even a few, is not an intelligence, but all of them together were a collective intelligence.

Comment: True, Fifth and the other human-form replicators were created from a multitude of nanobots like the Asurans, but also like the Asurans, after taking human form they pretty much became one entity that happened to be connected to the others - it was extremely rare (if it ever happened) for a human-form to willingly abandon its "self" to reintegrate with other replicator pieces.  (Unless that was what Fifth was doing when he "phased" through the wall on the Replicator ship; it wasn't obvious whether he was part of the wall or going through the wall)

Comment: I Agree with Tango. Also I would like to add that: The human form cylons are biological
The human form replicators where mechanical

Answer (score 2):

No, they were not.

While the Cylons were shown to be able to reproduce after mating with human beings, the Stargate universe replicators were never shown to have that ability. Also, the Stargate universe human form replicators could phase through solid matter, possessed superhuman levels of strength,were extremely durable (one was left in space and then came to "life" when he was retrieved) and were apparently programmable (Stargate Atlantis showed their Wraith combat code could be /deactivated/reactivated as necessary).

the Human form replicators in Stargate resembled android/gynoids in form and function rather than human beings. Human form Cylons in the BSG universe were indistinguishable from normal human beings except for the fact that there were limited models and they never deviated from a certain appearance.